# Como solucionar error al convertir Datetime en Miliseconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Ayuda!!

Estoy realizando mi primer aplicativo web en ASP.NET MVC y me encuentro con el problema de que estoy realizando una función para convertir una fecha en milisegundos.

Ejemplo tengo mi atributo en mi BD llamado **ACTIVITY_DATE** de tipo Datetime, el formato de ese Datetime es el siguiente `AAAA-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnn]`.

Necesito convertir en milisegundos, asi es como lo almacena en la BD `2019-08-13 16:10:36.223`

Esta es la consulta en mi modelo con la cual obtengo el **ACTIVITY_DATE**

**TicketDetailsModel.cs**

```
public static IQueryable<RecordsResult> ConvertActivityDateToMiliseconds(dbGoldenTicket db, long fechaMilisegundos)
    {

        return from tblTicket in db.TK_HD_TICKETS

               join tblRecord in db.TK_DT_RECORDS on tblTicket.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID equals tblRecord.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
               join tblEmployee in db.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES on tblRecord.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID equals tblEmployee.TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID into tempEmplo
               join tblServices in db.TK_CT_SERVICES on tblRecord.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID equals tblServices.TK_CT_SERVICES_ID
               join tblStatus in db.TK_CT_STATUS on tblRecord.TK_CT_STATUS_ID equals tblStatus.TK_CT_STATUS_ID
               from tblEmployee in tempEmplo.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where tblRecord.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID == fechaMilisegundos
               select new RecordsResult()
               {
                   RecordDate = tblRecord.ACTIVITY_DATE.ToString(),
               };

    }
```

Es importante dejar claro que TicketDetailsModel.ConvertActivityDateToMiliseconds devuelve la hora local

Y esta es mi función en mi controlador para convertir la fecha ACTIVITY_DATE en milisegundos

**TicketsController.cs**

```
public ActionResult ConvertMiliseconds()
    {
        using (var db = new dbGoldenTicket())
        {
            var query = TicketDetailsModel.ConvertActivityDateToMiliseconds(db, fechaMilisegundos);
            {
                long fechaMilisegundos = (long)(ACTIVITY_DATE - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
            }

            return fechaMilisegundos;
        }
    }
```

Estoy presentando los siguientes errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrían indicarme que estoy haciendo mal en mi código o darme la forma correcta de hacer la conversión de **ACTIVITY_DATE** a miliseconds

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad alguna respuesta presentada?

Answer (score 0):

Usa este codigo

```
(long)(ACTIVITY_DATE - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

No se exactamente en donde quieres agregar este dato, pero en alguna propiedad del objeto que estas modificando y debes de regresar debes de tener una propiedad de tipo long para hacer ese cambio de fecha. Donde ACTIVITY_DATE es tu fecha que quieres convertir a milisegundos.

```
long fechaMilisegundos = (long)(ACTIVITY_DATE - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: Puedes explicarme como lo utilizo en mi código

Comment: Edite mi comentario, espero te pueda ayudar

Comment: Revisa el codigo ya agregue la propiedad de tipo long

Answer (score 0):

El primer error es debido a que dentro de la función no tienes ninguna variable de nombre `ACTIVITY_DATE`, lo que tienes es query y db. Dentro de query que sera una lista de `RecordResults` según lo que veo en la primera función, tendrás una propiedad de nombre `RecordDate` que almacena el valor que quieres convertir.

El segundo error es debido al primero.

Comment: Como logro colocar la variable `ACTIVITY_DATE` dentro de la función